# How to print JSON in tabular format using jq

Tags: jq

Let's say I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "VarCharValue": "date"
    },
    {
      "VarCharValue": "time"
    }
  ],
  "Data": [
    {
      "VarCharValue": "12-13-2021"
    },
    {
      "VarCharValue": "23:22:33"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert this into a more conventional comma-separated log format like:

```
Date,Time
12-13-2021,23:22:33
```

Seems like the first step would be to remove the useless keys in this situation so that it looks like:

```
{
  "Data": [
      "date",
      "time"
  ],
  "Data": [
      "12-13-2021",
      "23:22:33"
  ]
}
```

I've read through the docs and manual and can't figure this part out.

Next would be to pull the arrays out of the objects and display as CSV which I can do with:
`jq -r .Data | @csv`

Can anyone assist with removing the keys here?

Comment: The JSON you've posted is syntactically valid but very suspicious because of the duplicated keys.  It is possible but quite difficult to handle such cases using jq, so before going to too much trouble, could you check that you really have to deal with such an anomalous case?

Comment: It's a one-off thing but your suggestion did the trick, so thank you again @peak!

Answer (score 1):

With your very dubious JSON, the following produces the result you want except for the header:

```
jq -r '[.Data[][]] | join(",")' weird.json
```

If you want the result to be guaranteed to be CSV, then use `@csv` instead of `join`.  You might also wish to consider `@tsv`.

It's easy enough to add the header, so I'll leave that to you, especially as there are more difficult potential issues to contend with. For example, the above won't work properly if the two "Data" key-value pairs are presented in a different order, or if you need to use the ordering in the first "Data" value to determine the correct ordering of the values in the second "Data" value.

Comment: My `jq` (jq-1.6) collapses the duplicate fields before processing anything and thus only ever reaches the last instance, i.e. `12-13-2021,23:22:33`. Using `--stream`, however, works, e.g. `jq --stream -sr 'map(last | strings) | (length/2) as $m | .[:$m], .[$m:] | @csv' weird.json`

Comment: Thank you @peak - it works for me. Any chance you can explain how your solution works so I can understand it?

Comment: And yes, dubious JSON agreed. This is how AWS Athena responds to queries via CLI believe it or not. I took a crack at figuring out what you did. It looks like the brackets that surround .Data mean we're creating a new array. I'm not sure why that's necessary but it definitely is. The first pair of brackets after .Data returns a single array of all key value pairs in the .Data objects. The second pair of brackets removes the keys in the key value pairs. I don't get this part.

Comment: @user2690966 - `.[]` works on both arrays and objects.  `join/1`, `@csv`, and `@tsv` all expect arrays as input. You can use `debug` to see what's going on behind the scenes.  Would it be worthwhile lodging a complaint with AWS Athena?